# Cannot share folders between Mac OS X based VMWare 7.1.1 and Guest Fedora 21 system

Tags: fedora, osx, vmware, file-sharing

I would like to share my Mac OSX 'Downloads' folder.  I set this up as a shared folder in vmware settings.

Currently, although I made a folder at `mnt/hgfs/Downloads`, it does not have the contents of my Mac OSX Downloads folder in it.

I ran the vmware install perl script `./vmware-install.pl` and at the end of the installation I get this message:

```
The filesystem driver (vmhgfs module) is used only for the shared folder 
feature. The rest of the software provided by VMware Tools is designed to
 work independently of this feature.

If you wish to have the shared folders feature, you can install the driver
 by running vmware-config-tools.pl again after making sure that gcc,
 binutils, make and the kernel sources for your running kernel are 
installed on your machine. These packages are available on your 
distribution's installation CD.
```

An Ask Ubuntu question has an accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74412/how-to-make-sure-that-gcc-binutils-make-and-the-kernel-source-are-installed) . Can anybody tell me the Fedora equivalent of `linux-source`, the fourth step in this answer or tell me how to share the 'Downloads' folder?

As requested by Warren, here is the full output from the tools install:

```
[dave@localhost ~]$ cd /home/dave/Documents/vmtools/vmware-tools-distrib/
[dave@localhost vmware-tools-distrib]$ ls
bin  doc  etc  FILES  INSTALL  installer  lib  vmware-install.pl
[dave@localhost vmware-tools-distrib]$ sudo ./vmware-install.pl 
A previous installation of VMware Tools has been detected.

The previous installation was made by the tar installer (version 4).

Keeping the tar4 installer database format.

You have a version of VMware Tools installed.  Continuing this install will 
first uninstall the currently installed version.  Do you wish to continue? 
(yes/no) [yes] y

Uninstalling the tar installation of VMware Tools.

Stopping services for VMware Tools

Stopping vmware-tools (via systemctl):                     [  OK  ]

Stopping Thinprint services in the virtual machine:
   Stopping Virtual Printing daemon:                                   done

File /etc/pulse/default.pa is backed up to /etc/pulse/default.pa.old.1.

The removal of VMware Tools 9.9.2 build-2496486 for Linux completed 
successfully.

Installing VMware Tools.

In which directory do you want to install the binary files? 
[/usr/bin] 

What is the directory that contains the init directories (rc0.d/ to rc6.d/)? 
[/etc/rc.d] 

What is the directory that contains the init scripts? 
[/etc/rc.d/init.d] 

In which directory do you want to install the daemon files? 
[/usr/sbin] 

In which directory do you want to install the library files? 
[/usr/lib/vmware-tools] 

The path "/usr/lib/vmware-tools" does not exist currently. This program is 
going to create it, including needed parent directories. Is this what you want?
[yes] 

In which directory do you want to install the documentation files? 
[/usr/share/doc/vmware-tools] 

The path "/usr/share/doc/vmware-tools" does not exist currently. This program 
is going to create it, including needed parent directories. Is this what you 
want? [yes] 

The installation of VMware Tools 9.9.2 build-2496486 for Linux completed 
successfully. You can decide to remove this software from your system at any 
time by invoking the following command: "/usr/bin/vmware-uninstall-tools.pl".

Before running VMware Tools for the first time, you need to configure it by 
invoking the following command: "/usr/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl". Do you want 
this program to invoke the command for you now? [yes] 

Initializing...


Making sure services for VMware Tools are stopped.

Stopping Thinprint services in the virtual machine:
   Stopping Virtual Printing daemon:                                   done
Stopping vmware-tools (via systemctl):                     [  OK  ]


The module vmci has already been installed on this system by another installer 
or package and will not be modified by this installer.

The module vsock has already been installed on this system by another installer
or package and will not be modified by this installer.

The module vmxnet3 has already been installed on this system by another 
installer or package and will not be modified by this installer.

The module pvscsi has already been installed on this system by another 
installer or package and will not be modified by this installer.

The module vmmemctl has already been installed on this system by another 
installer or package and will not be modified by this installer.

The VMware Host-Guest Filesystem allows for shared folders between the host OS 
and the guest OS in a Fusion or Workstation virtual environment.  Do you wish 
to enable this feature? [yes] 


Before you can compile modules, you need to have the following installed... 

make
gcc
kernel headers of the running kernel


Searching for GCC...
Detected GCC binary at "/bin/gcc".
The path "/bin/gcc" appears to be a valid path to the gcc binary.
Would you like to change it? [no] 

Searching for a valid kernel header path...
Detected the kernel headers at 
"/lib/modules/3.18.8-201.fc21.x86_64/build/include".
The path "/lib/modules/3.18.8-201.fc21.x86_64/build/include" appears to be a 
valid path to the 3.18.8-201.fc21.x86_64 kernel headers.
Would you like to change it? [no] 

make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only'
Using kernel build system.
/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.18.8-201.fc21.x86_64/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/3.18.8-201.fc21.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/message.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/dir.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/rpcout.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/hgfsUtil.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/cpName.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/request.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/module.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/link.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/bdhandler.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/transport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.o
In file included from include/linux/list.h:8:0,
                 from include/linux/preempt.h:10,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from include/linux/mmzone.h:7,
                 from include/linux/gfp.h:5,
                 from include/linux/mm.h:9,
                 from include/linux/pagemap.h:7,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:29:
/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.c: In function ‘HgfsPermission’:
include/linux/kernel.h:796:27: error: ‘struct dentry’ has no member named ‘d_alias’
  const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); \
                           ^
include/linux/list.h:688:40: note: in expansion of macro ‘container_of’
 #define hlist_entry(ptr, type, member) container_of(ptr,type,member)
                                        ^
include/linux/list.h:699:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_entry’
     ____ptr ? hlist_entry(____ptr, type, member) : NULL; \
               ^
include/linux/list.h:709:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_entry_safe’
  for (pos = hlist_entry_safe((head)->first, typeof(*(pos)), member);\
             ^
/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:1920:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_for_each_entry’
       hlist_for_each_entry(dentry,
       ^
include/linux/kernel.h:796:48: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
  const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); \
                                                ^
include/linux/list.h:688:40: note: in expansion of macro ‘container_of’
 #define hlist_entry(ptr, type, member) container_of(ptr,type,member)
                                        ^
include/linux/list.h:699:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_entry’
     ____ptr ? hlist_entry(____ptr, type, member) : NULL; \
               ^
include/linux/list.h:709:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_entry_safe’
  for (pos = hlist_entry_safe((head)->first, typeof(*(pos)), member);\
             ^
/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:1920:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_for_each_entry’
       hlist_for_each_entry(dentry,
       ^
In file included from include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:106:0,
                 from include/linux/compiler.h:54,
                 from include/uapi/linux/stddef.h:1,
                 from include/linux/stddef.h:4,
                 from ./include/uapi/linux/posix_types.h:4,
                 from include/uapi/linux/types.h:13,
                 from include/linux/types.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/./shared/driver-config.h:71,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:26:
include/linux/compiler-gcc4.h:14:34: error: ‘struct dentry’ has no member named ‘d_alias’
 #define __compiler_offsetof(a,b) __builtin_offsetof(a,b)
                                  ^
include/linux/stddef.h:17:31: note: in expansion of macro ‘__compiler_offsetof’
 #define offsetof(TYPE,MEMBER) __compiler_offsetof(TYPE,MEMBER)
                               ^
include/linux/kernel.h:797:29: note: in expansion of macro ‘offsetof’
  (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
                             ^
include/linux/list.h:688:40: note: in expansion of macro ‘container_of’
 #define hlist_entry(ptr, type, member) container_of(ptr,type,member)
                                        ^
include/linux/list.h:699:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_entry’
     ____ptr ? hlist_entry(____ptr, type, member) : NULL; \
               ^
include/linux/list.h:709:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_entry_safe’
  for (pos = hlist_entry_safe((head)->first, typeof(*(pos)), member);\
             ^
/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:1920:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_for_each_entry’
       hlist_for_each_entry(dentry,
       ^
In file included from include/linux/preempt.h:10:0,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from include/linux/mmzone.h:7,
                 from include/linux/gfp.h:5,
                 from include/linux/mm.h:9,
                 from include/linux/pagemap.h:7,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:29:
include/linux/list.h:711:35: error: ‘struct dentry’ has no member named ‘d_alia’
       pos = hlist_entry_safe((pos)->member.next, typeof(*(pos)), member))
                                   ^
include/linux/list.h:698:12: note: in definition of macro ‘hlist_entry_safe’
  ({ typeof(ptr) ____ptr = (ptr); \
            ^
/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:1920:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_for_each_entry’
       hlist_for_each_entry(dentry,
       ^
include/linux/list.h:711:35: error: ‘struct dentry’ has no member named ‘d_alia’
       pos = hlist_entry_safe((pos)->member.next, typeof(*(pos)), member))
                                   ^
include/linux/list.h:698:28: note: in definition of macro ‘hlist_entry_safe’
  ({ typeof(ptr) ____ptr = (ptr); \
                            ^
/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:1920:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_for_each_entry’
       hlist_for_each_entry(dentry,
       ^
In file included from include/linux/list.h:8:0,
                 from include/linux/preempt.h:10,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from include/linux/mmzone.h:7,
                 from include/linux/gfp.h:5,
                 from include/linux/mm.h:9,
                 from include/linux/pagemap.h:7,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:29:
include/linux/kernel.h:796:27: error: ‘struct dentry’ has no member named ‘d_alias’
  const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); \
                           ^
include/linux/list.h:688:40: note: in expansion of macro ‘container_of’
 #define hlist_entry(ptr, type, member) container_of(ptr,type,member)
                                        ^
include/linux/list.h:699:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_entry’
     ____ptr ? hlist_entry(____ptr, type, member) : NULL; \
               ^
include/linux/list.h:711:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_entry_safe’
       pos = hlist_entry_safe((pos)->member.next, typeof(*(pos)), member))
             ^
/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:1920:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_for_each_entry’
       hlist_for_each_entry(dentry,
       ^
include/linux/kernel.h:796:48: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
  const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); \
                                                ^
include/linux/list.h:688:40: note: in expansion of macro ‘container_of’
 #define hlist_entry(ptr, type, member) container_of(ptr,type,member)
                                        ^
include/linux/list.h:699:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_entry’
     ____ptr ? hlist_entry(____ptr, type, member) : NULL; \
               ^
include/linux/list.h:711:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_entry_safe’
       pos = hlist_entry_safe((pos)->member.next, typeof(*(pos)), member))
             ^
/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:1920:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_for_each_entry’
       hlist_for_each_entry(dentry,
       ^
In file included from include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:106:0,
                 from include/linux/compiler.h:54,
                 from include/uapi/linux/stddef.h:1,
                 from include/linux/stddef.h:4,
                 from ./include/uapi/linux/posix_types.h:4,
                 from include/uapi/linux/types.h:13,
                 from include/linux/types.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/./shared/driver-config.h:71,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:26:
include/linux/compiler-gcc4.h:14:34: error: ‘struct dentry’ has no member named ‘d_alias’
 #define __compiler_offsetof(a,b) __builtin_offsetof(a,b)
                                  ^
include/linux/stddef.h:17:31: note: in expansion of macro ‘__compiler_offsetof’
 #define offsetof(TYPE,MEMBER) __compiler_offsetof(TYPE,MEMBER)
                               ^
include/linux/kernel.h:797:29: note: in expansion of macro ‘offsetof’
  (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
                             ^
include/linux/list.h:688:40: note: in expansion of macro ‘container_of’
 #define hlist_entry(ptr, type, member) container_of(ptr,type,member)
                                        ^
include/linux/list.h:699:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_entry’
     ____ptr ? hlist_entry(____ptr, type, member) : NULL; \
               ^
include/linux/list.h:711:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_entry_safe’
       pos = hlist_entry_safe((pos)->member.next, typeof(*(pos)), member))
             ^
/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:1920:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘hlist_for_each_entry’
       hlist_for_each_entry(dentry,
       ^
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only/inode.o] Error 1
Makefile:1385: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/3.18.8-201.fc21.x86_64'
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'vmhgfs.ko' failed
make: *** [vmhgfs.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-s61CNS/vmhgfs-only'

The filesystem driver (vmhgfs module) is used only for the shared folder 
feature. The rest of the software provided by VMware Tools is designed to work 
independently of this feature.

If you wish to have the shared folders feature, you can install the driver by 
running vmware-config-tools.pl again after making sure that gcc, binutils, make
and the kernel sources for your running kernel are installed on your machine. 
These packages are available on your distribution's installation CD.
[ Press Enter key to continue ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is the need for linux-source; you already seem to have the necessary header files installed, otherwise the config script would have given you an error after the "Searching for a valid kernel header path..." line.

Rather, I think you're running into the same problem that everyone using a recent Linux kernel is having with various VMWare products--VMWare doesn't yet support kernels newer than 3.13.0-45. You can read more about the problem at the VMWare forums: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/502554. The short answer is to either wait for an updated set of tools from VMWare, try the community patches available at https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches, or stick with an older kernel.